# Capture heap snapshot (Chrome dev tools) while running Protractor tests

Tags: node.js, protractor, heap-dump, v8-profiler

I want to create an automated Protractor test that creates a heap snapshot after opening the application in Chrome and after performing a series of actions via protractor.
Then to upload in Chrome dev tools in the memory tab both snapshots and compare them. The problem is that the application classes are not available in the snapshot, only test related information.
Is there a way to do this while running Protractor tests? The snapshot libraries I've tried are heapdump, v8-profiler-next and several others but with the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any solution? I have same question ?

Comment: Not with Protractor but do have one with Cypress and should work with Playwright

Comment: @DDana I'm looking for a Cypress solution, could you please share what you found?

Comment: I've integrated lighthouse and v8

In my test:
` const thresholds = {
    performance: 10,
    accessibility: 50,
    'first-contentful-paint': 30000,
    'largest-contentful-paint': 30000,
    interactive: 40000,
    seo: 10,
    pwa: 10,
  };

  const lighthouseConfig = {
    formFactor: 'desktop',
    screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
  };

  cy.lighthouse(thresholds, lighthouseConfig);
  cy.window().then(win => {
  if (typeof win.gc === 'function') {
        win.gc();
  }
 });
  cy.task('heapinfo').then((result) => {
    cy.log('Heap info: '+result);  
  })`

Comment: plugins/index.js:
`
 const { lighthouse, prepareAudit } = require("@cypress-audit/lighthouse");
 const v8 = require('v8');
 on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    prepareAudit(launchOptions);
  if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
   launchOptions.args.push('--js-flags=--expose-gc');
   }
  return launchOptions;
 });

  on('task', {
    lighthouse: lighthouse(),
  })

  on('task', {
    heapinfo: ()=>{
      v8.setFlagsFromString('--trace_gc');
      return JSON.stringify(v8.getHeapStatistics());
    }
  });`